# Generating vertices programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a 3D object (`SCNPlane`) i want to divide this plane into squares.   Idea is to divide the plane into tiles and each tile has its own textures (texture coordinates).  And the number of tiles is controlled by user interface.

[image]

In the above image the plane is divided into 3 tile along x axis and 3 tile along y axis and each tile is further divided into two triangles.  Right now i am trying to use the for loops to generate these vertices.  I am new to this metal/opengl world if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just math...

```
var x0 = 0, x1 = 1000
var y0 = 0, y1 = 1000

var ySplit = 4
var xSplit = 6

for y in (0..<ySplit).reverse() {

    var localY0 = y * ((y1 - y0) / ySplit)
    var localY1 = (y+1) * ((y1 - y0) / ySplit)

    for x in 0..<xSplit {

        var localX0 = x * ((x1 - x0) / xSplit)
        var localX1 = (x+1) * ((x1 - x0) / xSplit)

        //Now you can easily get any vertex/square/triangle set from the given (x0,y) (x1,y1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what i did, yours i much cleaner.  Is this is the only way or there is any api available in graphics kit like metal or OpenGLES that will actually divide the plane into vertices and return  the vertices

Answer (score 0):

`SCNPlane` has `widthSegmentCount` and `heightSegmentCount` properties that do just that (see [SCNPlane Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnplane)).

**Edit**
If you need custom texture coordinates then you'll have to build a custom geometry using `SCNGeometry.init(sources:elements:)` and compute vertex positions yourself.

Note that in Swift you have the handy

```
SCNGeometryElement.init(indices:primitiveType:)
```

and the following convenience initializers in iOS 10, tvOS 10, macOS 10.12 and watchOS 3:

```
SCNGeometrySource.init(normals:)
SCNGeometrySource.init(textureCoordinates:)
SCNGeometrySource.init(vertices:)
```

Comment: thanks mnuages, but it does not return the vertices.  I have to add texture coordinates to the vertices.

Comment: thanks again.  didn't saw your edit.  thats what i ended up doing SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource, textureSource], elements: [geometryElement])